# Is there a glibc API that can find the default handing application for a MIME type on linux?

Tags: c, freedesktop, mime-types

I want to find the default handling application in my C program. Is there a C API with same functionality as `xdg-mime query default mime-type` on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`glibc` doesn't know anything about MIME types; the API functions live at the level of desktop environment APIs, and the `freedesktop.org` recognize that harmonizing them is an impossible task so they only specify the shell-level interface.  You either use that via `popen()` or code for a particular desktop environment.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Could you give me some hint about using system() to get this information?

Comment: Actually, not `system()` but rather `popen()` so you can capture the output of `xdg-mime`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there's a C API for querying mime-types in the same way that xdg-mime works.  xdg-mime is just a shell script that queries your desktop environment (Gnome, KDE, or other), and runs the appropriate command to get the MIME type from that DE's internal configuration.

You could replicate the behaviour of the shell script, or just call the shell script directly from C.  The [XDG Utils web page](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/) doesn't seem to show anything about a C API.